# Functions and inverses proof

Tags: calculus, functions

> 1. Consider the subset $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ defined by $D = \{(x,y):|x|+|y| = 1\}$. Describe this set in words. Is it a function?
> 2. Let $f,g$ be functions, such that $$g\circ f(x) = x,~~\forall x\in~ D(f)\\f\circ g(y) = y,~~\forall y\in D(g)$$
>      Prove that $g = f^{-1}$.

1. You have a subset $D$ where it is defined as the modulus of $x$ and $y$ when added equals $1$. If I square that, I notice that it will result in $x^2+y^2=1^2$ which then can be associated with the Pythagorean theorem. Is this correct? Can anyone elaborate futher?
2. To have an inverse it has to be one-one. Which means that if $g$ is an inverse of $f$ then $D(g) = R(f) \implies R(g)=D(f)$. So then I have to prove that?

Comment: The Pythagorean stuff is not really right. First note that $|x|+|y|=1$, when $x$ and $y$ are non-negative, just says $x+y=1$. So the first quadrant part of $|x|+|y|=1$ is very familiar. Then reflect in the $x$-axis and/or the $y$-axis. That does not change the absolute values. You should get a "diamond."

Comment: @AndréNicolas Kind of confused how exactly is it a diamond? I have a point x and a point y where both added equals 1. So lets say x = 0 and y = 1. How does that make a diamond?

Comment: You have a lot of points, for example all $(x,y)$ with $x$, $y$ non-negative such that $x+y=1$. That's the line **segment** joining $(0,1)$ to $(1,0)$. You will also get the line segment joining $(0,1)$ to $(-1,0)$, also the one joining $(-1,0)$ to $(0,-1)$, also $(0,-1)$ to $(1,0)$. Draw it, a diamond (in this case a square turned by $45^\circ$).

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see the diamond now thanks. But the first question is not a function correct?

Comment: That's right. If you have the graph of a function, any **vertical** line can hit the graph in at most one point. Some vertical lines hit the diamond in two points. Another way: when $x=0$, $y$ could be $1$ or it could be $-1$. But if $y$ is a function of $x$, there is only one $y$-value for any given $x$-value.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks a lot Andre!

Comment: @Q.matin: What do want to do with $f^{-1}$ and $f$? $f^{-1}$ exists iff $f$ is onto and one-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1. just to verify the basic definition of a function, that is:

> If $(x_1,y_1)\in f, (x_1,y_2)\in f$ then $y_1=y_2$.

Now consider $x_1=0$, so you can find $|y|=1$ or $y_1=1,~y_2=-1$ and $y_1\neq y_2$.

Comment: Thanks Babak. Is the modulus sign an absolute value sign or the magnitude?

Comment: @Q.matin: I assumed it is the first one. Moreover, I agree with Ittay about your secnd approach. Make it clearer. ;)

Comment: I see from your def of a function Babak that 1 is not a function since $y_1 \ne y_2$ is that correct?

Comment: @Q.matin: Yes. Furthermore, I want to add something which was covered by Ittay. Try to make a graph of your relation. Make a vertical line to intersect the graph. If it intersects the graph in just one point so the relation is function, otherwise it fails.

Comment: Is that the vertical line test you are referring to?

Comment: @Q.matin: Yes. For the second, use the definition, you added in Ittay's answer.

Comment: How will I proceed in proving that? Do I just have to show that $D(g) = R(f) \implies R(g)=D(f)$?

Comment: I like this definition. Usually I see it this spelled out in words (the definition) - but this is mathematically nice and concise! +1

Answer (score 2):

To get a feeling for what the shape is formed by $D$ try to find several actual $(x,y)$ points that are in $D$. When you found one try to see if you increase or decrease the $x$ coordinate and still obtain a point in $D$. Can you now figure out what shape $D$ is?

Your formulation of the second question is very vague. It would help if you make it clearer and supply the definition of $f^{-1}$ that you were given.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $g$ which is stated in the book. Also, for part 1 is it an absolute value sign or magnitude sign?

Comment: it's an absolute value sign (the absolute value of a number is also called its magnitude). I'm afraid I still have no idea what part 2 is asking.

Comment: I think I misread your question, when you said the second question is vague do you mean my attempt at a solution is vague or the actual question?

Comment: the actual question.

Comment: $D()$ represents the domain. Is that more clear?

Comment: no, not clear at all. I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to ask.

Comment: The def the book has for $f^{-1}$ is. "Let $f$ be a one-one function with domain $D(f)$ in $A$ and range $R(f)$ in $B$. If $g=\{(b,a) \in B \times A :(a,b)\in f\}$ then $g$ is a one-one function with domain $D(g)=R(f)$ in $B$ and with range $R(g)=D(f)$ in $A$. The function $g$ is called the function iverse to $f$."

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but I dont know how to clarify it any more because I wrote it exactly like the book has it.